# AttributeRouting returns Forbidden when route mirrors directory structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8, attributerouting

I'm using MVC 5.2.2 with AttributeRouting.

Imagine the code below, for example:

```
public sealed class DocumentsController : Controller
{
    [Route("documents")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This has a route of `/documents`.

Now, imagine my project has a directory called 'documents' at the root.

IIS will serve me with a **403.14 Forbidden** because directory browsing is disabled. It is disabled by design. No, I don't want to enable it.

I assume there may be some kind of Web.config magic that needs to happen.

How can I setup MVC routing to override IIS when there is an applicable route as in this situation, yet continue to serve the IIS level Forbidden when there is not a valid route?

Comment: The problem is that the request is being answered by IIS Before the MVC stack has a chance to get that request.  Most people encounter this issue with bundle configs (styles and script folder keys matching file structure). Maybe you'd be able to find a solution in that related topic.  The simple answer is to not have file system paths that you want MVC to respond to.

Comment: @pnm The linked answer actually has an answer for the issue. Setting `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` solves this problem.